# How to (de)serialise a JSON where a field is either a String or an Object using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON that is returned from an API so I can't change it and the problem is that one of the properties sometimes is a empty string and sometimes it is an Object.

Sometimes when i call it foo is a empty string

```
{ 
 "foo" : "",
 "bar" : 0
}
```

and at other times it is an object

```
{
 "foo" : {"baz": 11},
 "bar" : 2
}
```

Is there a way to do this using Jackson? The only way I found so far is writing a custom deserializer/serializer-pair. The problem I have with that approach is that this is a deeply nested JSON structure and the offending property is close to the root...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, configure your `ObjectMapper` to accept the empty string as a `null` object.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);
```

The above is for Jackson 2+. There is a similar configuration for Jackson 1, but the `configure` is a little different.

Comment: Thnx for a great answer. For those of you still using Jackson 1+ the solution is to add `mapper.configure(Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT, true);` instead.